# WinUI3 | DataGrid ItemsSource DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, datagrid, winui-3

I want to make a WinUI3 (Win32) application with a DataGrid from Microsoft.Toolkit.
I use MVVM.

My XAML code:

```xml
`
        <controls:DataGrid
            Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
            ItemsSource="{Binding DataTableViewModel}"
            Margin="12"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            AutoGenerateColumns="True"
            CanUserSortColumns="False"
            CanUserReorderColumns="True"
            CanUserResizeColumns="True"
            ColumnHeaderHeight="32"
            MaxColumnWidth="400"
            HeadersVisibility="Column"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            SelectionMode="Extended">
        </controls:DataGrid>
```

The problem is that binding DataTable doesn't work. Error message:
`Error: Converter failed to convert value of type '' to type 'IBindableIterable'; BindingExpression: Path='DataTableViewModel' DataItem='DemoApp.ViewModel.ViewModel'; target element is 'CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI.Controls.DataGrid' (Name='null'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IBindableIterable').`

I can bind a collection and it does work, but the problem is I need a `DataTable` to fill the datagrid as I need it (for example headers are the first column and not the first row...).

How is it possible to bind a `DataTable` to a WinUI3 DataGrid?

Comment: Binding is more or less deprecated in favor of x:Bind, have tou seen this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56565378/uwp-toolkit-datagrid-how-to-bind-collectionviewsource-to-itemssource-of-datagr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is it possible to bind a DataTable to a WinUI3 DataGrid?

**The Windows Community Toolkit DataGrid is essentially composed of many ListViews**, you need to use the DataGrid.ItemsSource property to bind to a **collection**.

Here are the [official documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/datagrid_basics#binding-a-datagrid-to-a-data-source) for your reference

Comment: Thanks for the info, I think that is currently still a limitation :-(

Answer (score 1):

The only way to bind a DataTable to your datagrid is converting it to collection (list, observableCollection) and bind it.